# Is $\mathbb{C}[x] \subseteq \mathbb{C}[x, y]/(y^4 + y^3 + y^2 + y + 1)$ an integral ring extension?

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, integral-extensions

> I would like to prove or disprove that $S = \mathbb{C}[x, y]/(y^4 + y^3 + y^2 + y + 1)$ is integral over $\mathbb{C}[x]$.

Just using the definition of integrality might not be the correct approach, because then I have to find a monic polynomial $f \in \mathbb{C}[x]$ such that any element in $\mathbb{C}[x, y]/(y^4 + y^3 + y^2 + y + 1)$, which is a polynomial of $2$ variables, is a root of $f$. My idea is to show that $\mathbb{C}[x, y]/(y^4 + y^3 + y^2 + y + 1)$ is (or not) finitely generated as a $\mathbb{C}[x]$-module. If this is not true, is $S$ at least integral over $\mathbb{C}$ ?  Unfortunately, I don't know how to proceed. 
I am grateful for any help.

Comment: If $R=\mathbb C[x]$ you can show that $S$ is a free $R$-module of rank 4, a basis consisting from $\{1,y,y^2,y^3\}$.

Comment: Can you please give me more details ?

Comment: Just perform a long division of a polynomial in $y$ with coefficients in $\mathbb C[x]$ with respect to $y^4 + y^3 + y^2 + y + 1$.